# ADF vs. DF what is the difference between augmented and the standard Dickey-Fuller test?

Tags: time-series

ADF test supposed to remove the all the structural effects (autocorrelation) in the time series and then tests using the same procedure as DF test.

Could anybody explain in simple terms what is the difference between those two tests?

Comment: This should be covered in econometrics / time series textbooks. Try Zivot ["Modelling Financial Time Series with S-PLUS, Second Edition"](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/manual.pdf) Chapter 4, mainly p. 114 and onwards. If it's not there, try another textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, the [book](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/manual.pdf) referenced in Richard Hardy comment has the answer.

The book says, and I quote:

> The unit root test described above are valid if the time series $y_t$ is well characterized by an AR(1) with white noise errors. Many financial time series, however, have a more complicated dynamic structure that is captured by a simple AR(1) model. Said and Dickey (1984) augmented the basic autoregressive unit root test to accommodate general ARMA(p, q) models with unknown orders and their test is referred to as *augmented Dickey-Fuller* (ADF) test.

The "test described above" is the standard Dickey-Fuller test.

Above quote is available on p. 120 of the [book](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/manual.pdf) (or 140 of the pdf)